# Need to send N requests to the server using curl in 1 second?

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to do the load testing on the server by using cURL command. How can I send N number of requests in 1 second to the server? for e.g if iam sending 100 requests to the server then all the 100 should go in 1 second. I have incorporated the cURLS in the bash script and tried to automate the test. However, I am able to send 100 requests in 24 seconds or more.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using Apache AB benchmarking tools http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

It's a lot more effective than just cURL, and you can send thousands of requests per second.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer but our scope to do the load testing is with cURL only. I would like to learn the newer ways for sure but for now let me know if i can call the server using cURL N times in 1 second or less.

Comment: the cURL is get for example-curl -X GET -w "\n" "$HOSTNAME_VALUE/get?Interest=CE&DeviceID=$line"